# How can I find how much RAM are VMware Player VMs using on Linux?

Tags: debian, memory, vmware

I am running Debian Jessie 64-bit on a computer with 8 GB of RAM. This is my memory usage according to `htop`(with a fairly large Firefox session) before starting a guest VM that has 4 GB allocated.

[image: Without VMware, I have 1297 MB used]

This, is my memory usage according to `htop`, with my guest VM started and after being put to do some work.

[image: With VMware, I have 1326 MB used]

Unlike Windows, which reports accurately how much RAM are VMs consuming on my system, Linux does not report such information. As a result, I often run into scenarios where I start too much VMs thinking I have the memory to fit them when that is not true, and I end up enduring like 3 solid minutes of my system having to suddenly push an entire gigabyte of RAM to swap.

Where can I see the RAM that my VMs are actually using?

Comment: I think this could be helpful: [How to see top processes by actual memory usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-by-actual-memory-usage)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've started a VM with 4GB allocated, and top reports a vmware process using 4GB plus change, so what's the problem?

Comment: I am seeing 1326 MB of RAM in use, instead of something more like 5297 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most readable script; I initially wrote it for myself and later discovered this question (and that this might be helpful to others):

```bash
vmfolder="$HOME/vmware"
vmwarebinary='/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx'

function add {
    awk '{tot += $1} END{print tot}'
}

vmusage="$(ps wauwx | grep " $vmwarebinary " | grep vmx\$ | awk '{print (int($6/1024/1024*100)/100) " GiB " $3 " avg%CPU for " $(NF)}' | sed 's@'"$vmfolder"'/\([^ ]*\)/.*@\1@')"
tot="$(echo "$vmusage" | add)"
avail="$(free -mw | grep '^Mem:' | awk '{print (int($8/1024*100)/100)}')"
realavail="$(echo "$avail-$tot" | bc)"

echo "$vmusage" | sort -nr
echo "Total                     $tot GiB"
echo "Claimed available memory: $avail GiB"
echo "Truly available memory:    $realavail GiB"
```

Note the `vmfolder` path that should be configured to where your VMs are.

I don't know if different `free` versions or clones all output the same columns or syntax. This was tested on Debian 11, probably works on other Debian-based OSes as well. The VMware this was tested with is VMware Workstation 16.

Protip: run with `watch -d -n 10 thescript.bash` to have it highlight changes for you. It will look like this:

[image: screenshotted output of the above watch command]

Where:

- 17.9GB total: the total memory used by all VMs
- 27.5GB claimed available memory: what your `free` binary says is available (lies!)
- 9.6GB truly available memory: one minus the other; i.e. how much memory I expect to be truly available for new VMs or other software on the host system.

I haven't made my system run out of RAM on purpose so I don't know for certain sure whether this is correct, but it seems at least like a good indication. Hope it helps!